# How did they come up with the equation for calculating module of 2 numbers "a%b = a-b*(a//b)"

Tags: python-3.x

if we try different example you can see it satisfy the equation

```
print(13 % -4)
print(-10 % 9)
```

the question is where did they get the equation 
a%b = b*(a//b)-a from

Comment: The equation is actually `a%b = a-b*(a//b)`

Answer (score 0):

It is the intuitive way to define a "remainder" operation, and also it's actually in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), you just have to tweak the equation a littlebit.

> The floor division and modulo operators are connected by the following
>   identity: x == (x//y)*y + (x%y). Floor division and modulo are also
>   connected with the built-in function divmod(): divmod(x, y) == (x//y,
>   x%y).

So subtracting `(x//y)*y` from `x == (x//y)*y + (x%y)` gives you `x%y == x - (x//y)*y`.